# Проблема с выполнением запроса WHERE LIKE в SQLite из Android приложения.

Tags: android, sqlite, like

Встроенный в Андроид SQLite, пишу небольшое приложение, которое должно реализовывать поиск по одному полю по принципу LIKE, а другое поле для найденных записей возвращать.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: тен (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT gruppe FROM drugs WHERE drugname LIKE тен
```

"тен" - это искомая строчка,
"gruppe" - возвращаемое поле,
"drugname" - поле по которому поводиться сравнение
"drugs" - таблица
Приложение собирается, компилируется (0 warnings 0 errors), Запускается, база создаетсяб наполняется, в момент query приложение падает с указанным выше экзепшном. Буду рад любой помощи.
ниже код выполнения запроса:

```
database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();  
String stQuery = "SELECT " + DBHelper.KEY_GROUP + " FROM " +   
DBHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBHelper.KEY_NAME + " LIKE "+   
editText.getText().toString();  
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(stQuery, null);  
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {  
int groupIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_GROUP);  
do {  
  stGroup = cursor.getString(groupIndex);  
} while (cursor.moveToNext());  
}  
cursor.close();
```

Comment: вы забыли кавычки: `select group from tab where key like '%тен%'`

Answer (score 0):

Можно запрос попробовать переделать. Попробуйте так

```
 Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{DBHelper.KEY_GROUP}, DBHelper.KEY_NAME + " LIKE ", new String[]{editText.getText().toString()}, null, null, null);
```